# Connecting 2 Django Projects on Different Servers

Tags: python, django, pythonpath

For reasons out of my control, 2 Django projects were placed on 2 different AWS servers, both using the same RDS AWS database.

I want Project B to be able to access and manipulate the models (tables) used in Project A (where they were originally created).

Is this at all possible? Importing the Project A app over the network via the `PYTHONPATH` in some way?

Comment: you wouldn't be able to just import it over a server and make changes as it executes, you would need to modify A to allow a connection from B to make manipulations.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen could you elaborate on how that would be done

Comment: I don't know enough about this to post a half decent answer but I believe the relevant technology is [`RPC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), allowing you to basically send code from B to be executed on A.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry...I lack the reputation to comment otherwise I would not have posted.

I think in this situation, you may need to make use of the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

This way you can simple authorize the projects to talk to each other, DRF comes with httpbasic built in, but you probably should try to set up some type of hashed token as part of the auth.

I found [this guide](http://www.techstricks.com/api-authentication-django-and-android-apps/) recently...although it's specific to mobile devices, it's probably one of the better walkthroughs of the DRF.

Comment: very cool, so you're suggesting having Project B ask Project A for JSON representation of the model and use it in that way?

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be the most straightforward way of doing it. I'm in the process of beginning a similar implementation as well, so hopefully someone more experienced on the API stuff can chime in. The only caveat I've seen is that serializing django models sometimes sucks (more complex models won't easily serialize for JSON passing), but depending on your models it might be a non issue.